# How to decode ResponseAPDU to XML from an Austrian e-card?

Tags: java, xml, smartcard, apdu, asn.1

I try to read information from an Austrian e-card to get the first name and last name.

What works for now is: Access the card, send APDU commands and get the information as byte array.

How can I convert the received byte array to XML to extract the needed data?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.smartcardio.Card;
import javax.smartcardio.CardChannel;
import javax.smartcardio.CardException;
import javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal;
import javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.ResponseAPDU;
import javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals;
        try {
            terminals = factory.terminals().list();
            CardTerminal terminal = terminals.get(0);
            Card card = terminal.connect("*");
            CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
            // Select the MF
            byte[] aid = { (byte) 0xD0, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01 };
            ResponseAPDU resp = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, aid));
            System.out.println("Response: " + resp.toString());
            // Select the Personaladata-file
            byte[] aid2 = { (byte) 0xEF, 0x01 };
            resp = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xA4, 0x02, 0x04, aid2));
            System.out.println("Response: " + resp.toString());
            // Get the data from the file
            resp = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(0x00, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF));
            System.out.println("Response: " + resp.toString());
            System.out.println("Response String: " + new String(resp.getData()));
            card.disconnect(false);
        } catch (CardException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to transform that data into an XML structure (and according to what schema). However, the byte array that I received from my SV card looks like an ASN.1 DER encoded TLV structure:

```
30 xxxx
SEQUENCE
    30 18
    SEQUENCE
        06 08
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            2A28000A01040101
            => OID 1.2.40.0.10.1.4.1.1 (SV number)
        31 0C
        SET
            12 0A
            NumericString
                nnnnnnnnddddmmmmyyyy
                => SV number: NNNN DDMMYY
    30 0F
    SEQUENCE
        06 08
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            2A28000A01040103
            => OID 1.2.40.0.10.1.4.1.3 (Card sequence number)
        31 03
        SET
            02 01
            INTEGER
                xx
                => Card sequence number: xx
    30 xx
    SEQUENCE
        [...]
    30 xx
        SEQUENCE
        06 03
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            55042A
            => OID 2.5.4.42 ({joint-iso-itu-t(2) ds(5) attributeType(4) givenName(42)})
        31 xx
        SET
            0C xx
            UTF8String
                4D69636861656C
                => Given name: "Michael"
    30 xx
    SEQUENCE
        06 03
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            550404
            => OID 2.5.4.4 ({joint-iso-itu-t(2) ds(5) attributeType(4) surname(4)})
        31 xx
        SET
            0C xx
            UTF8String
                526F6C616E64
                => Surname: "Roland"
    30 xx
    SEQUENCE
        [...]
    30 1D
    SEQUENCE
        06 08
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            2B06010505070901
            => OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.1 ({iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) security(5) mechanisms(5) pkix(7) pda(9) dateOfBirth(1)})
        31 11
        SET
            18 0F
            GeneralizedTime
                yyyyyyyymmmmdddd3132303030305A
                => Date of birth: YYYY-MM-DD 12:00:00Z
    30 0F
    SEQUENCE
        06 08
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER
            2B06010505070903
            => OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.9.3 ({iso(1) identified-organization(3) dod(6) internet(1) security(5) mechanisms(5) pkix(7) pda(9) gender(3)})
        31 03
        SET
            13 01
            PrintableString
                4D
                => Gender: M (male)
```

So this seems to follow something like the following ASN.1 notation:

```
SVPersonGrunddaten ::= SEQUENCE OF Attribute
Attribute ::= SEQUENCE {
    attributeName OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
    attributeValue SET OF AttributeType }
AttributeType ::= CHOICE {
    numericString NumericString,
    integer INTEGER,
    utf8String UTF8String,
    time GeneralizedTime,
    printableString PrintableString }
```

Where the attributes for the given name and the surname are

```
givenName Attribute ::= {
    attributeName 2.5.4.42,
    attributeValue { utf8String "Given Name" }
}
surname Attribute ::= {
    attributeName 2.5.4.4,
    attributeValue { utf8String "Surname" }
}
```

So in order to get the given name and the surname, you would parse the TLV structure, search for the OIDs of those two elements, and decode the associated values as a UTF8 string.

Note that simply assuming that the fields are there at the exact positions does not seem to be a good idea. For instance, there is a field `30 xx ...` (a field of type `Attribute`) before the given name field that seems to be only present if there is an academic/professional title (e.g. "Dr." in my case) printed on the card. Similarly, there is another optional field for academic suffixes (such as "M.Sc.") that is only present if such a suffix is printed on the card. Though all other fields were always in the same order on my cards, I'm not sure if that's even required.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint, here are code to decode the DER byte array to String

```
ASN1InputStream input = new ASN1InputStream(resp.getData());
            ASN1Primitive p;
            try {
                while ((p = input.readObject()) != null) {
                    // System.out.println("DEBUG: " + ASN1Dump.dumpAsString(p));
                    // Sozialversicherungsnummer
                    ASN1Sequence asn1 = ASN1Sequence.getInstance(p);
                    ASN1Sequence seq = DLSequence.getInstance(asn1.getObjectAt(0));
                    ASN1Set svn = DLSet.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(1));
                    DERNumericString svnObject = DERNumericString.getInstance(svn.getObjectAt(0));
                    System.out.println("SVN: " + svnObject.getString());

                    // Vorname
                    seq = DLSequence.getInstance(asn1.getObjectAt(2));
                    svn = DLSet.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(1));
                    DERUTF8String stringObject = DERUTF8String.getInstance(svn.getObjectAt(0));
                    System.out.println("Vorname: " + stringObject.getString());

                    // Nachname
                    seq = DLSequence.getInstance(asn1.getObjectAt(3));
                    svn = DLSet.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(1));
                    stringObject = DERUTF8String.getInstance(svn.getObjectAt(0));
                    System.out.println("Vorname: " + stringObject.getString());

                    // Geschlecht
                    seq = DLSequence.getInstance(asn1.getObjectAt(5));
                    svn = DLSet.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(1));
                    DERPrintableString charObject = DERPrintableString.getInstance(svn.getObjectAt(0));
                    System.out.println("Geschlecht: " + charObject.getString());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Just be aware that the index of the given name, surname, and gender fields may vary, so `asn1.getObjectAt(2)` will not always give you the given name, etc. This is, for instance, the case when there are additional fields for a prefixed academic title or a suffixed academic degree. I just checked with my previous cards and those fields are simply absent if there is no title or suffix.